# Base case in recursive function is not stopping recursion typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, machine-learning, neural-network, calculus

I am working on a machine learning algorithm in TypeScript and have a partial derivative method meant to replicate this:
[image]
Here is my recursive method to do so:

```
private pd(a : Activation, w : Weight, t : number) : number { //Takes partial derivative of activation with respect to weight
        return sigDeriv(this.sums[t][a.l][a.j].val)*(a.l == w.l && a.j == w.j ?
            this.activations[t][a.l - 1][w.k].val
            : sumFunc(this.activations[t][a.l - 1].length, 1,
                async k => await this.weights[a.l][a.j][k].val*this.pd(this.activations[t][a.l - 1][k], w, t)
            )
        );
    }
```

The problem is that, even after the base condition (`a.l == w.l && a.j == w.j`) is reached, the function continues to execute and eventually reaches the input layer (where there are not weights), causing an error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? **When I ran the function and logged the value of the base case, it would return true when appropriate, but the function would continue executing, causing an error.**

Comment: Did you understand the synchronicity problem I mentioned or do you want me to explain more?

Comment: It does not seem that synchronicity is the issue; the gradient step with respect to each weight is found in a for loop, which calls my function and waits for it to finish. Based on console output, each weight is derived in the proper order. If there is an issue, it would be with activations, but I am thinking the for loop inside of sumFunc might be the issue.

Comment: As sumFunc does not have an await, I suppose you don't need the result of the recursive call in it, right?

Comment: Well, sumFunc is called from the pd function, which is always called with an `await`

Comment: pd is not `async`, and cannot have await. Neither has `sumFunc`. Only the anonymous lambda calling pd is `async`, and therefore returning a Promise.

Comment: Async wasn't the issue though. I fixed it by modifying my base case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to change my base condition to be more general. While the first condition stopped the function when the activation multiplied by the weight being differentiated for was found, the function continued trying to differentiate the rest of the activations, beyond where the weight had an impact on the function. Basically, I ended up at `∂/∂w(aw + a2w2 + ...)`, and `pd` would return the activation being multiplied by `w` when that term was differentiated, but continue with recursion for the other terms, which are no longer impacted by `w` and therefore will never reach the base condition. Thus, the solution was to return `a`'s value whenever the function reached the weight's layer, as the aformentioned derivative evaluates to `(a + 0 + ...)`.

```
private pd(a : Activation, w : Weight, t : number) : number { //Takes partial derivative of activation with respect to weight
    return sigDeriv(this.sums[t][a.l][a.j].val)*this.pdSum(a, w, t);
}

private pdSum(a : Activation, w : Weight, t : number) : number { //Handles sum statement in recursive derivative definition
    if(a.l == w.l) return this.activations[t][a.l - 1][w.k].val; //This line solves the problem

    return sumFunc(this.activations[t][a.l - 1].length, 1,
        async k => await this.weights[a.l][a.j][k].val*this.pd(this.activations[t][a.l - 1][k], w, t)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a problem of parenthesis. Try:

```
((a.l == w.l && a.j == w.j) ? … : … )
```

Because here, the test is only done on `a.j == w.j`

(operator ? : has more priority than &&)

But as seen by Scott, this will not correct your problem. We don't see the full code, so can't be sure, but it could be a problem of synchronicity (I see you are using async/await). If w can be asynchronously modified, then your test may be false when it should not…

Comment: Doesn't that *weaken* the test, making it *more* likely to be true than expected?

Comment: How could that weaken the test, if it is the test the OP wished to make? Or there is something I did not understand…

Comment: The expression actually being evaluated is true in every situation the OP's expected expression was, and also in others, so the code would execute the base case *at least* as often as expected, not less.

Comment: Yeah my problem is that the base case is not stopping the algorithm, but only checking one case would make the algorithm stop too early. Anyway, I tried this edit and it did nothing for my algorithm.

Comment: Edited to give a new suggestion.